# Accessing a member function of an object in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have an array full with objects of a class I created. I want to access functions of each of them but I don't know how. I tried it with a pointer but it didn't work. Sorry for the question being noobie, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to help people help you, post the code and the compiler error messages.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried with a pointer, and the errors you got?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access an array element just like any other object:

```
MyClass array[42];
array[12].do_something();
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, then please describe what you're doing in more detail (ideally with example code), and what's going wrong (including whatever error messages you get).

Comment: Is it the same for 2D arrays?

Comment: @OmarZeidan Yes, but with two sets of `[index]` for the two dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, apparently I forgot some really basic stuff, I'm ashamed of myself. My programs working finally. I'll post the code next time, sorry for that :)

Comment: Could you tell me how that works with a 2D vector and an iterator? It's not working out for me yet.

Comment: @OmarZeidan: Please update the question to show us what you're trying to do. The question refers to an array, not a "2D vector" (whatever you mean by that).

Answer (score 0):

So what is wrong with `myArray[index].foo()` in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried it with a pointer but it didn't work, for pointer you use something like this

```
MyClass *array[23]; // or MyClass **array if you don't want to specify the static size of that array

for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 23; i++ )
{
   array[i] = new MyClass();
}

for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 23; i++ )
{
   array[i]->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: so the actual array is created in the first for-loop? didn't undestand that too much. and by the way, is it important for you to define an unsigned int in the loop-header, do you always pay attention to such things? thanks