# Class array with multiple types? How to access one type in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Here's a small portion of my code:

```
class Student
{
    private:
        string ID, fname, lname, level;
        double gpa;
}
```

So let's say that I make an array a[] of type Student, is there a way to access just the double 'gpa' of each array element? Not exactly sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I need to learn how to google better because I feel like this shouldn't be too hard to look up but I still couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836455/accessing-a-member-function-of-an-object-in-an-array

Comment: What happens when you write the obvious `studentArray[0].gpa`? You tried that, right?

Comment: @Arkadiy I tried studentArray.gpa[]  which produced errors. I couldn't find the correct syntax so I thought I could ask on this forum, sorry.

Comment: Please add the code you tried and the errors. Otherwise we're not answering *your* question, we're answering a general question that is simply too obvious to take seriously.

Comment: @Arkadiy your way worked. I'm just trying to get through this c++ class and couldn't find the answer I was looking for in my book or online. If people thought the problem was too simple to justify an answer then they didn't have to answer. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array

```
std::array<Student, 10> students;
```

You could say

```
for (auto const& student : students)
{
    std::cout << student.gpa << " ";
}
```

You can obviously do this for an arbitrary element as well

```
students[i].gpa = 4.0;
```

Of course you have to make sure you have `public` methods to access these members if they are specified `private`

```
class Student
{
public
    Student() = default;
    Student(double _gpa) : gpa(_gpa) {}

    double get_gpa() const { return gpa; }
    void set_gpa(double _gpa) { gpa = _gpa; }

private:
    double gpa = 0.0;
}
```

Then

```
students[i].set_gpa(4.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see CoryKramer showed you how to do it with a `std::array` but if you just want to use a normal array, here is what you should do:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

class Student
{
public:
  double get_gpa() {return gpa;}
  void set_gpa(double _gpa) {gpa=_gpa;}
private:
  std::string ID, fname, lname, level;
  double gpa;
};

int main() {
  Student a[30];
  //Initialize
  for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    a[i].set_gpa((double)i/7.5);
  }
  //Print out
  for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    printf("a[%i].gpa = %f\n",a[i].get_gpa());
  }
}
```

Essentially you just do `Student a[30];` to create thirty students in an array, then you can initialize their values to be different with a `for` loop or input from a *"Teacher"*. Lastly you can print them using another for loop later like so: `printf("%f\n",a[i].get_gpa());` or with `std::cout` it would be `